# WCF service giving error not found and method not allowed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, dojo

I tried setting up a WCF service in a demo application that when I tested it within the application it worked fine when running it. I then created the same service and tried to apply it to a dojo application where I call the service from a xhrpost function and the following error occurs

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
(Not Found)    http://localhost:51541/Service1.svc/load_data
```

After opening it up in the browser `http://localhost:56252/Service1.svc`, I then tested it using wcftestclient.exe and all methods within there worked. Is there something I am missing here.

webconfig portion:

```
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://locaxxxxx:56252/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

EDIT:

I found it referencing another port as mentioned but after removing the other project I now got the following error:

```
Failed to load resource http://localhost:56252/Service1.svc/load_data
```

Comment: Can you browse to the port the application is using? It's configured for port 56252, but the error shows that it's using 51541. Do you programmatically change the service URL at some point?

Comment: I just saw that thanks; but I don't think I am changing it anywhere. That was the port the demo app used when I ran it the first time. Perhaps I should remove the demo project from the solution.

Comment: removed other project and now got this error: Failed to load resource http://localhost:56252/Service1.svc/load_data

Comment: port 51541 is the port the web app is running on

Comment: Compare the binding in your config file with the one generated by the wcftestclient.exe.